# Interior.Color returning the wrong interior colour

Tags: excel

I am trying to hide rows that have a white background on a spreadsheet There are rows with other color backgrounds too.

```
For I = 63 To xRg.Count
    'Testing from the 63rd row using cells in column 'U'
        If xRg.Range("U" & I).Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
            xRg.Range("U" & I).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else
            xRg.Range("U" & I).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    Next 'i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox I
```

All rows with white backgrounds must be hidden based on the cell color of the cell in column 'U'. The code is returning a White interior color when the interior color is green. The row is hidden when it should'nt be.

[image]

Comment: Are the color applied through conditional formatting?

Comment: use `xRg.Range("U" & I).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbWhite`

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for the prompt response and apologies for my late reply. The link in this message point to the spreadsheet. I made the changes you suggested, but no luck. There is no conditional formatting in the spreadsheet. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/dviafjdzdi7dla4/cuttings%20planning%20visual%20David%20Done%20%282%29.xlsm?dl=0] Thanks Chris